# Unable to scroll listview items

Tags: android, listview

I have layout with few text boxes and checkboxes. Between them is listview. When I add three or more items I can't see them in listview, the listview does not have scroll bar.

This is my layout:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="163dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!-- -------------HERE IS MY LISTVIEW--------------- -->                

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayoutGlavni"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutGlavni"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reklamacija dobavljaču" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
                    android:text="Prenamjena robe" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Otpis robe" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox3"
                    android:text="Upozorenje djelatniku" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Obuka djelatnika" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox5"
                    android:text="Održavanje" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.68" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Is there something missing inside layout code or this must be solved through code?

Comment: The layout you posted does not contain a `ListView` but more importantly it isn't even valid...

Comment: It contains, I've checked.

Comment: I see, what should this layout look like? Quite frankly this whole xml looks insane with a lot of unnecessary views. It can be greatly simplified. But as I said. This is not valid xml. Please fix it. And your `ListView` is placed inside a `ScrollView` which will not work. Nested scrollable elements are not possible in Android.

Comment: And `fill_parent` is deprecated, don't use it. Use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I agree, the xml looks horrible but I dont know how to arrange layouts to look perfect. Designing UI is very hard to me :(

Comment: @Josef no  listView in your layout

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @maveň I thought so too, but it is there in the middle somewhere. Extremely unconventional usage of a `ListView` but just keep looking. It's nested in a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never put a listview in a scrollView, because Listview is autoScrollable when its size increases than the screen.

Please refer to this link. Makers of Listview component.
Here you can find the best approaches of How to use a listview properly

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've removed ScrollView and it it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: the same all are saying you can't use two scrolling view in each other

Answer (score -1):

I could suggest you to put only the ListView in a ScrollView. I think it will work, because I already tried it. So please try with something like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="163dp"

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Nesting scrollable elements is not possible in android. Every time something like this works it is purely coincidental.

Comment: I don't say to put a ScrollView int oanother ScrollView, but to put the ListView into a ScrollView. When you don't agree, what can you suggest then?

Comment: How does it make any difference if you put a `ScrollView` inside a `ScrollView` or a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`? They are both scrollable elements. And there is no alternative, that's what I am saying. You cannot have two scrollable elements inside one another.

Comment: Every time you may want to put two scrollable elements inside one another there is another much simpler solution which avoids having two nested scrollable elements.